# Avoid old data when using useEffect to fetch data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My problem is, when a custom hook uses `useEffect` with `useState` (e.g. to fetch data), the custom hook returns stale data (from the state), after dependencies change but before useEffect is fired.

Can you suggest a right/idiomatic way to resolve that?

---

I'm using the React documentation and these articles to guide me:

- [A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)
- [How to fetch data with React Hooks?](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/)

I defined a function, which uses `useEffect` and which is meant to wrap the fetching of data -- the source code is TypeScript not JavaScript but that doesn't matter -- I think this is "by the book":

```
function useGet<TData>(getData: () => Promise<TData>): TData | undefined {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState<TData | undefined>(undefined);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData()
      .then((fetched) => setData(fetched));
  }, [getData]);

  // (TODO later -- handle abort of data fetching)

  return data;
}
```

The App routes to various components depending on the URL -- for example here is the component which fetches and displays user profile data (when given a URL like `https://stackoverflow.com/users/49942/chrisw` where `49942` is the "userId"):

```
export const User: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> =
  (props: RouteComponentProps) => {

  // parse the URL to get the userId of the User profile to be displayed
  const userId = splitPathUser(props.location.pathname);

  // to fetch the data, call the IO.getUser function, passing userId as a parameter
  const getUser = React.useCallback(() => IO.getUser(userId), [userId]);

  // invoke useEffect, passing getUser to fetch the data
  const data: I.User | undefined = useGet(getUser);

  // use the data to render
  if (!data) {
    // TODO render a place-holder because the data hasn't been fetched yet
  } else {
    // TODO render using the data
  }
}
```

I think that's standard -- if the component is called with a different userId, then the `useCallback` will return a different value, and therefore the `useEffect` will fire again because `getData` is declared in its dependency array.

However, what I see is:

1. `useGet` is called for the first time -- it returns `undefined` because the `useEffect` hasn't fired yet and the data hasn't been fetched yet
2. `useEffect` fires, the data is fetched, and the component re-renders with fetched data
3. If the `userId` changes then `useGet` is called again -- `useEffect` will fire (because `getData` has changed), but it hasn't fired yet, so for now `useGet` returns stale data (i.e. neither new data nor `undefined`) -- so the component re-renders with stale data
4. Soon, `useEffect` fires, and the component re-renders with new data

Using stale data in step #3 is undesirable.

How can I avoid that? Is there a normal/idiomatic way?

I don't see a fix for this in the articles I referenced above.

A possible fix (i.e. this seems to work) is to rewrite the `useGet` function as follows:

```
function useGet2<TData, TParam>(getData: () => Promise<TData>, param: TParam): TData | undefined {

  const [prev, setPrev] = React.useState<TParam | undefined>(undefined);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<TData | undefined>(undefined);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData()
      .then((fetched) => setData(fetched));
  }, [getData, param]);

  if (prev !== param) {
    // userId parameter changed -- avoid returning stale data
    setPrev(param);
    setData(undefined);
    return undefined;
  }

  return data;
}
```

... which obviously the component calls like this:

```
  // invoke useEffect, passing getUser to fetch the data
  const data: I.User | undefined = useGet2(getUser, userId);
```

... but it worries me that I don't see this in the published articles -- is it necessary and the best way to do that?

Also if I'm going to explicitly return `undefined` like that, is there a neat way to test whether `useEffect` is going to fire, i.e. to test whether its dependency array has changed? Must I duplicate what `useEffect` does, by explicitly storing the old userId and/or getData function as a state variable (as shown in the `useGet2` function above)?

---

To clarify what's happening and to show why adding a "cleanup hook" is ineffective, I added a cleanup hook to `useEffect` plus `console.log` messages, so the source code is as follows.

```
function useGet<TData>(getData: () => Promise<TData>): TData | undefined {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState<TData | undefined>(undefined);

  console.log(`useGet starting`);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`useEffect starting`);
    let ignore = false;
    setData(undefined);
    getData()
      .then((fetched) => {
        if (!ignore)
          setData(fetched)
      });
    return () => {
      console.log("useEffect cleanup running");
      ignore = true;
    }
  }, [getData, param]);

  console.log(`useGet returning`);
  return data;
}

export const User: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> =
  (props: RouteComponentProps) => {

  // parse the URL to get the userId of the User profile to be displayed
  const userId = splitPathUser(props.location.pathname);

  // to fetch the data, call the IO.getUser function, passing userId as a parameter
  const getUser = React.useCallback(() => IO.getUser(userId), [userId]);

  console.log(`User starting with userId=${userId}`);

  // invoke useEffect, passing getUser to fetch the data
  const data: I.User | undefined = useGet(getUser);

  console.log(`User rendering data ${!data ? "'undefined'" : `for userId=${data.summary.idName.id}`}`);
  if (data && (data.summary.idName.id !== userId)) {
    console.log(`userId mismatch -- userId specifies ${userId} whereas data is for ${data.summary.idName.id}`);
    data = undefined;
  }

  // use the data to render
  if (!data) {
    // TODO render a place-holder because the data hasn't been fetched yet
  } else {
    // TODO render using the data
  }
}
```

And here are the run-time log messages associated with each of the four steps I outlined above:

1. `useGet` is called for the first time -- it returns `undefined` because the `useEffect` hasn't fired yet and the data hasn't been fetched yet

   ```
   User starting with userId=5
   useGet starting
   useGet returning
   User rendering data 'undefined'
   ```
2. `useEffect` fires, the data is fetched, and the component re-renders with fetched data

   ```
   useEffect starting
   mockServer getting /users/5/unknown
   User starting with userId=5
   useGet starting
   useGet returning
   User rendering data for userId=5
   ```
3. If the `userId` changes then `useGet` is called again -- `useEffect` will fire (because `getData` has changed), but it hasn't fired yet, so for now `useGet` returns stale data (i.e. neither new data nor `undefined`) -- so the component re-renders with stale data

   ```
   User starting with userId=1
   useGet starting
   useGet returning
   User rendering data for userId=5
   userId mismatch -- userId specifies 1 whereas data is for 5
   ```
4. Soon, `useEffect` fires, and the component re-renders with new data

   ```
   useEffect cleanup running
   useEffect starting
   UserProfile starting with userId=1
   useGet starting
   useGet returning
   User rendering data 'undefined'
   mockServer getting /users/1/unknown
   User starting with userId=1
   useGet starting
   useGet returning
   User rendering data for userId=1
   ```

In summary the cleanup does run as part of step 4 (probably when the 2nd `useEffect` is scheduled), but that's still too late to prevent the returning of stale data at the end of step 3, after the `userId` changes and before the second `useEffect` is scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

In a reply [on Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/cwellsx/status/1127751139053789184), @dan_abramov wrote that my `useGet2` solution is more-or-less canonical:

> If you do setState inside of render [and outside of `useEffect`] to get rid of stale state, it shouldn't ever produce a user-observable intermediate render. It will schedule another re-render synchronously. So your solution should be sufficient.
>
> It's the idiomatic solution for derived state, and in your example state is derived from ID.
>
> [How do I implement getDerivedStateFromProps?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops)
>
> (In longer term there will be a different solution for data fetching altogether that doesn’t involve effects or setting state. But I'm describing what we have today.)

The article referenced from that link -- [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) -- explains what the root cause of the problem is.

It says that the problem is, expecting the "controlled" state passed-in to `User` (i.e. the userId) to match the "uncontrolled" internal state (i.e. the data returned by the effect).

The better thing to do is to depend on one or the other but not mix them.

So I suppose I should return a userId inside and/or with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the data each time the `useEffect` is called inside `useGet`:

```
function useGet<TData>(getData: () => Promise<TData>): TData | undefined {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState<TData | undefined>(undefined);

  React.useEffect(() => {

    setData(undefinded) // initializing data to undefined

    getData()
      .then((fetched) => setData(fetched));
  }, [getData]);

  // (TODO later -- handle abort of data fetching)

  return data;
}
```

Comment: I think that doing it inside of `useEffect` is too late -- because in what I called step #3, the `userId` has just changed but the `useGet` function returns stale data before `useEffect` is even run.

Comment: @ChrisW yes, it's true, since `useEffect` runs after render already finished. But since component is re-rendered immediately user even doesn't notice stale data rendered, do they?

Comment: The `User` component is re-rendered (i.e. rebuilds its DOM) using stale data in step 3, after the userId has changed -- that's bad, that's the problem I want to fix -- it's being rendered using data which doesn't match the passed-in userId.