# Avoid stale data prop in React child component

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, fetch, react-props

From my parent component, I am passing down the state variable data as a prop to the child component. The data is fetched via fetch/UseEffect. The URL params can be modified by clicking a button, and depending on the param, a completely different object is fetched, which needs to be handled differently in the child component.

```
export default function ParentComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [param, setParam] = useState('')
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data= await (await fetch(`https://myapi.com/?param=${param}`)).json()

      setData(data)
      setLoading(false)
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [param])

return (<div>
    { isLoading ? 
      (<span>Loading...</span>)           
      : 
  (<div>
    <button onClick={() => setParam('something')}>Click me</button>
      <ChildComponent data={ data } />
  </div>

      </div>)
   }
}
```

My problem is that whenever I click the button (set the state) in the parent, which triggers a rerender, the components rerender twice (causing below console.log to print twice), which I'd dare say is expected behavior, once because of setParam, once when fetchData and setData is completed).

```
export default function ChildComponent(props) {
    const { data } = props

    return (
    <div>

    // Prints twice, first stale data, then when fetchData has completed.
    { console.log(data )}

    </div>)
}
```

My question to you guys, as I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours now, having read ChrisW's post here ([Avoid old data when using useEffect to fetch data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56096560/avoid-old-data-when-using-useeffect-to-fetch-data)) and the React.js Hooks FAQ (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html), is how on God's green earth (sorry any atheist!) I only ever get to access the newly fetched, non-stale data prop in the child component, and ignore the stale one? Is it through refs? UseEffect? (I know I can make a UseEffect in the child component with data as a dependency, however, what should I do with it, I am after all trying to control what is being returned?)

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to consider [useMemo API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to solve this issue:

```
const MemoizedChildComponent = useMemo(({ data }) => <ChildComponent data={data} />, [data]);
```